# Unexpected result with ceil() function

Tags: c++, c++11, ceil

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long long n,m;
    double ans;

    cin>>n>>m;

    ans=log(m)/log(n);

    cout<<ans<<" "<<ceil(ans);
}

**input**
581
196122941
**output**
3 4
**expected output**
3 3
```

This is a simple c++ code where the input is 2 integer number and i have to calculate the log division of those numbers and find the ceil() of that result. But when i give the following input it shows that the division result is 3 but the ceil() of that result is 4. But ceil(3) should give 3. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's something like 3.0000000000000004441. `cout` prints the first 6 digits. Try this code `cout<< setprecision(20) << ans<<" "<<ceil(ans);`

Answer (score 5):

The result is something like 3.0000000000000004441. `cout` prints only the first 6 digits. There is also some kind of rounding involved but it's not the usual rounding. On my machine `3.000005` is printed as `3` and `3.000006` is printed as `3.00001`. Print more digits with

```
cout<< setprecision(20) << ans<<" "<<ceil(ans);
```